# Can't parse all the links recursively from a certain block of a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script to parse all the links recursively until the dead-end from the left sided window under `Any Department`. As the selectors throughout all the depth are identical, I thought the script will be able to get all the links but when I run it I could notice that it parses few links superficially.

[webpage address](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/ref=zg_bs_nav_0)

I've tried so far with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/ref=zg_bs_nav_0'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36'
    while True:
        r = s.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
        if not soup.select("li:has(> span.zg_selected) + ul > li > a[href]"):break
        for item in soup.select("li:has(> span.zg_selected) + ul > li > a[href]"):
            link = item.get("href")
            print(link)
```

Current output:

```
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/530886031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_1_kinc/261-4895013-9879242
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/530887031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_1_kinc/261-4895013-9879242
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/4824719031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_1_kinc/261-4895013-9879242
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/13065180031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_1_kinc/261-4895013-9879242
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/13065217031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_2_13065180031
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/13065201031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_2_13065180031
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/13065326031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_2_13065180031
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/13065236031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_2_13065180031
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/13065329031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_2_13065180031
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/13065181031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_2_13065180031
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/13065237031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_2_13065180031
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/13065312031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_2_13065180031
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/13065242031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_2_13065180031
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/13065244031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_3_13065242031
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/13065259031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_3_13065242031
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/13065243031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_3_13065242031
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/13065287031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_3_13065242031
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/13065282031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_3_13065242031
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/13065290031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_3_13065242031
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/13065295031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_3_13065242031
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/13065294031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_3_13065242031
```

I can see lot more links in there in different depth. To be clearer, I'm interested in all the links in different depth from the block in the image attached.

[image]

> How can I get all the links from left sided window recursively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your code is not recursive and an actual recursive piece of coding would be one way of obtaining what you want. In the following code I have taken the added precaution of adding a set to which all seen links are added. I was not sure whether there was a possibility of getting into an infinite loop if a link could appear more than once so I test to see if a link has already been processed before I process it again:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def find_links(session, link, indent, seen_set):
        print(' ' * indent * 4, link, sep='')
        r = session.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
        for item in soup.select("li:has(> span.zg_selected) + ul > li > a[href]"):
            link = item.get("href")
            if link not in seen_set:
                seen_set.add(link)
                find_links(session, link, indent + 1, seen_set)

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36'
    link = 'https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/ref=zg_bs_nav_0'
    find_links(s, link, 0, set([link]))
```

**Update**

The code has been modified to use your generator (with my indentation support, which can be ignored) and threading to speed up the processing a bit. There is a slight change to the logic: When the links on a page are read in, the pages for those links are then retrieved concurrently before recursing for processing. It's just a change as to when a page is retrieved. There also seems to be far greater number of links today: **4392**

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import functools


def get_page(s, link):
    resp = s.get(link)
    return resp.text


def get_links(executor, s, link, page, indent, seen_set):
    yield link, indent
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
    links = [item.get("href") for item in soup.select("li:has(> span.zg_selected) + ul > li > a[href]") if item.get("href") not in seen_set]
    pages = executor.map(functools.partial(get_page, s), links)
    for i, page in enumerate(pages):
        link = links[i]
        seen_set.add(link)
        yield from get_links(executor, s, link, page, indent + 1, seen_set)


def main():
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36'
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as executor:
            link = 'https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/ref=zg_bs_nav_0'
            page = get_page(s, link)
            for elem, indent in get_links(executor, s, link, page, 0, set([link])):
                print(' ' * 4 * indent, elem, sep='')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints (I can only show a portion since I have exceeded maximum post length -- there are 316 links):

```
https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/ref=zg_bs_nav_0
    https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/530886031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_1_kinc/257-8192800-2632148
        https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/567111031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_2_530886031
            https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692008031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_3_567111031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692009031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692008031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692012031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692008031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692020031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692008031
            https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/610657031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_3_567111031
            https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/610653031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_3_567111031
            https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/610651031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_3_567111031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692040031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_610651031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692032031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_610651031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692046031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_610651031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692048031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_610651031
            https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692049031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_3_567111031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/610670031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692049031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692050031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692049031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/610668031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692049031
            https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692063031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_3_567111031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692064031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692063031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/610662031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692063031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692065031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692063031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692066031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692063031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692067031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692063031
                    https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692068031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_5_6692067031
                    https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692069031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_5_6692067031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692070031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692063031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692071031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692063031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692073031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692063031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692074031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692063031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692075031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692063031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692076031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692063031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692077031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692063031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/16008439031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692063031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692078031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692063031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692079031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692063031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692080031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692063031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692081031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692063031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692082031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692063031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692083031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_6692063031
            https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/610655031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_3_567111031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692095031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_610655031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692099031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_610655031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692101031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_610655031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692103031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_610655031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692108031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_610655031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692113031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_610655031
            https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/567123031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_3_567111031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692341031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_567123031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692345031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_567123031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-text/6692348031/ref=zg_bs_nav_kinc_4_567123031
                https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/bestsellers/digital-
```

Comment: When I try like [this](https://pastebin.com/L6qB7Lhi), I get more than 1000 unique links. Few duplicate links are in there, though. Recursive logic in the linked code is taken from your solution.

Comment: I gave you the wrong count. I ran this under jupyter notebook and to get the count I copied and pasted the output into an editor and looked at the line count. But I clearly miscopied all of the output (it was in a scrollable window). This time I just redirected the output directly to a file. My new count is: **1173**

Comment: By the way, the statement: `if not soup.select("li:has(> span.zg_selected) + ul > li > a[href]"): return` is unnecessary. I think I will remove it.

Comment: It stands to reason that if you took my logic (more or less) and got a totally different count, then I gave you an incorrect count (or you could have just tried to run my program and seen for yourself).

Comment: That is not what I meant @Booboo. I just wanted to know the difference. Thanks.